# authorization web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am restricting access to the Account folder using below:

```
<location path="Account">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

and access to the Default.aspx using

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

but how do I restrict access to a specific file in the Account folder rather than the entire folder?

I tried the following but did not work

```
<location path="Account\ChangePassword.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<location path="Account/ChangePassword.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization> 
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization> 
  </system.web> 
</location>
```

Comment: haha... them backslaskes in asp.net kill me

thanks branislav

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Also you don't need to use <deny users="?"/> <allow users="*"/> Only the first one will do the job.